# robots.txt url blocking

Tags: seo

I am trying to set up robot.txt for a webpage but the disallow wont work when test it

want to block a thank you page

http://designs.webelevate.net/wordpress/index.php/contact-thank-page/

using the code

Disallow: /index.php/contact-thank-page/

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The line you have right now will only block URLs at root. e.g. it will block the below URL (Note: wordpress/ is removed).

http://designs.webelevate.net/index.php/contact-thank-page/

To expand this to include the URL you noted either add /wordpress into the disallow or add a * in the path like below.

```
Disallow: */index.php/contact-thank-page/
```